# IIS8.5 .NET Core 3.1 Web API POST - No response externally/on public domain

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5

I have a fully working Web API, as long as I'm making calls from the host environment. If I make a Postman call remotely to my IIS 8.5 server using the public DNS hostname it "Could not get any response".

**UPDATE 21/05/2020:** I've narrowed the issue down to `app.UseHttpsRedirection()`, which leads me to believe that the CORS preflight (OPTIONS) request that's sent is being rejected somehow once it enters the server through the redirection middleware. Probably thinks its malicious and rejects but if anyone can provide insight as to why this is, it would be **GREATLY** appreciated.

Please note the following:

- Its a .NET Core 3.1.4 Web API template with two controllers.
- These controllers can only perform POST (JSON Data From Body) requests.
- I'm using IIS 8.5 on Windows Server 2012 R2, it exists alongside other live .NET framework apps.
- I've installed the .NET Core hosting 3.1.4 package on the IIS server.
- To visit it an example would be https://localhost/[MyProjectsName]/api/Customers
- I've given the app its own dedicated app pool and dedicated identity/user to run on.
- I've set .NET CLR version to `No Managed Code`.
- The app is published with dotnet.exe using a TFS2015 build agent with the following arguments

```
publish "[CSPROJ LOCATION]"  -c "TEST" -o "$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\published" -f "netcoreapp3.1" -r "win81-x64"
```

- I'm using InProcess hosting and specified `webBuilder.UseIIS()`.
- I've tried `UseUrls("http://*:80;https://*:443")` although I fear that's only relevant to Kestrel users.
- I've defined `<AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>` within my CSPROJ.
- For the sake of troubleshooting I've opened up my CORS policy with the following...

```cs
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(name: specificOrigins,
                    builder =>
                    {
                        builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains();
                    });
            });
```

- ...And added `app.UseCors(specificOrigins)` to the Configure method within Startup.
- I've also added `[EnableCors("_AllowSpecificOrigins")]` attribute to the controllers.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If more code snippets or info is needed I'll try to update if possible. First time poster, long time lurker, so very unfamiliar with Stack Overflow posting.

Comment: what is your site binding in iis? try to set the IP address instead of the hostname for binding and access site remotely with the IP address. set firewall rule to access the port number externally. Ensure Asp.Net Core Host Bundle is installed.

Comment: Hi Jalpa, big thanks for the quick response! The host binding on IIS itself is a standard http://*:80 and https://*:443. Asp.Net Core 3.1.4 Host Bundle is installed per above notes. 

I've actually narrowed down the cause of the issue to HTTPS redirection middleware, so any insight as to why that would potentially affect a CORS preflight request would be great!

Comment: did you installed iis cors module?